Using custom font together with dynamic type size in SwiftUI
So far I have been using the modifier .dynamicTypeSize every where to define the text size like that:
Text("Hello, World")
    .dynamicTypeSize(.xxxLarge)

Now I also want to define a custom font like AmericanTypewriter for exemple but it seems incompatible with the other modifier.
All the tutorials I found on the subject, including Apple doc, seem to mention a different type of dynamic type size, based on .body, .title, .largeTitle, etc. not on .xLarge, .xxLarge and so on, like:
Text("Hello, world!")
    .font(Font.custom("MyFont", size: 32, relativeTo: .title))

I tried to substitute .xxLarge to .title in the above expression, but this does not work.
Then I tried to remove the `.dynamicTypeSize' modifier. Here is my text code:
Text(etLogique ? ET : OU)
    .font(.custom("AmericanTypewriter", size: 18))
    .bold()
    .pastille(color: Color("fondbleu"))
    .onTapGesture {
        etLogique.toggle()
    }

ETand `OU are the two symbol characters to represent logical 'AND' and 'OR' and when touching the text you toggle between one and the other.
let ET = "\u{2229}"
let OU = "\u{222A}"

By the way, pastille()is the format extension:
extension View {
    func pastille(color: Color) -> some View {
        self.padding(6)
            .background(color)
            .border(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Color.black/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, width: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/1/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            .cornerRadius(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/20.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:20).stroke(.black, lineWidth: 1))
    }
}

The result is a bit weird. The AND symbol is appearing smaller than the OR one:



Why do you want to substitute .xxLarge for .title? That doesn't make sense. You might have a fundamental misunderstanding about dynamic type. Can you explain clearly how .font(Font.custom("MyFont", size: 32, relativeTo: .title)) does not do what you want to do?

You seem to assume that .dynamicTypeSize is the primary way to control the text size. While this modifier does change the size of the text, it does not respect the user's dynamic type settings (this modifier is designed to do that). Most of the time you should respect the user's dynamic type setting, and you should use .font(...) to control the text size. This way, the text size scales with respect to the user's dynamic type setting.

"How to keep homogeneous with other texts in the view when using custom fonts." This is not something you should do. What looks good for the system font might not look good for your custom font. This is whole purpose of the .custom(_:size:relativeTo:) factory. This allows you to specify the size that "looks good" for your font for a specific text style. The system then scales this using a scale factor. This scale factor is a function of both the user's dynamic type settings (or whatever you have set using .dynamicTypeSize) and the text style.

@Sweeper, It is not that I want to substitute .xxLarge for .title. I just mentioned that I tried it because all docs about joint use of .dynamicTypeSize and custom font only show examples with .title etc whereas the docs about dynamicTypeSize, including apple doc [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dynamictypesize] are based on .xxLarge etc

.font(Font.custom("MyFont", size: 32, relativeTo: .title)) would probably do what I want if I was using the dynamicTypeSize that is based on  the .enum .title etc which I am not doing, since I based my code on the a.m. doc. And you are probably right to say that I have a fundamental misunderstanding about dynamic type. That is why I was asking. For the rest of your comments, sorry I do not catch you.

So the answer is simple then - stop putting .dynamicTypeSize everywhere and use .font(...) to change the text size instead. Does that satisfy you?

@Sweeper see update of the post

Okay now you are asking a completely different question. American Typewriter doesn't even have glyphs for U+2229 and U+222A, so a fallback font is used. The fallback (at least on my machine) is ".HiraKakuInterface-W3", which just so happens to have very different glyphs for U+2229 and U+222A. If you use another font like "HiraMinProN-W3", the two glyphs look roughly the same.

Foolowing @Sweeper's advice, I updated my code like this:
Text(etLogique ? ET : OU)
    .font(.custom("HiraMinProN-W3", size: 22))
    .bold()
    .pastille(color: Color("fondbleu"))
    .onTapGesture {
        etLogique.toggle()
    }

Which seems to work. I had to try to find out 22 is the size that matches with the next Text which has no size modifier.

Dynamic Type is an accessibility feature that allows users to scale the UI. DynamicTypeSize is used in SwiftUI to get the Dynamic Type and tweak the UI for a better visual result (WWDC 24 session on the matter 7:20)
In order to set the size of your font in SwiftUI, you can either:

use the defined semantic system fonts:

.font(.body)

use the system font with a custom size (NOT changing with dynamicType):

.font(.system(size: 15))

use the system font with a custom size (changing with dynamicType):

.font(.system(size: UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body).scaledValue(for: 15)))

if you're using a custom font:

.font(Font.custom("MyCustomFont", size: 15, relativeTo: .body))
Some time ago I made a google drive spreadsheet with a graph to visualize the scaling properties of the different semantic system Fonts Apple provides, in case you want to use a custom font and are wondering which text style to use.

I find it a pity not to be able to use this .dynamicTypeSize as it is described in Apple's doc. I find the semantic of the system fonts more intended for a document. My app is not a document. I don't have titles, paragraphs and text body (except in the help section). I am just displaying text items with smaller or larger characters according to the context!

You should read this page https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/scaling_fonts_automatically/ where Apple explains what's dynamic type and how you should size your fonts.

Thanks @Damien. And you should read that one : [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dynamictypesize] and also the title of my post : I mentioned SwiftUI, not UIKit. But you are right, if you are not familiar with it, simply don't use it ! ;-)

My bad for the UIKit doc, there’s still good infos in the page imho, as Apple try to be consistent between UIKit and SwiftUI. The documentation you linked states this API is to get dynamic type information, not to set it. There’s an exemple of using SwiftUI DynamicTypeSize in this WWDC session if you want to take a look https://developer.apple.com/wwdc24/10074

@SimonW Feel free to accept this answer if you judge it's answering your question. It helps other people in finding an answer to their problem (quicker).
